Combinatorial rectangle packing problem
Take the numbers 1, 2, and 3, and make a list of all possible unordered pairs (ie {1,1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,2}, {2,3} and {3,3}). Interpreting these as the dimensions of rectangles, you get 6 rectangles that fit perfectly together into a 5x5 square. An example is shown below.

Doing the same with the numbers 1 to $n$ only seems to work when $n$ is 1 (trivially) or 3 (case shown above).
You can compute the total area covered by the 1 to $n$ combination bricks using the formula $A(n) = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(3n+1)}{24}$, which is A001296. However, I have been unable to prove this formula never results in a square number excluding $n=1$ and $n=3$ (and even if $A(n)$ was square for some other value, it's not necessarily possible to pack the rectangles into a square.)
I've run some code and no other square values were found up until the code started to run into floating point errors. Are there any other values that let you pack a square?

The equation $k^2=A(n)$ with a known point $(0,0)$ or $(1,1)$ is an elliptic curve, and finding all integral points on elliptic curves is quite a deep mathematical subject that is suitable for computers. It can be done, but it is tricky.

Note that elliptic curves have only finitely many integer solutions but yeah, finding them can be tricky.

For what it's worth, there are a number of references and links at the OEIS page for the sequence $A(n)$: https://oeis.org/A001296

Suppose that $A(n)=m^2$ for some natural numbers $n$ and $m$. That is $$n(n+1)(n+2)(3n+1)=24m^2.$$
This Diophantine equation can be elementarily split into the system of Generalized Pell's equations as follows.
Let $n=xa^2$, $n+1=yb^2$, $n+2=zc^2$, and $3n+1=td^2$, where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are natural numbers and $x$, $y$, $z$, and $t$ are square-free natural numbers.
We have $x\ne y$, because otherwise $1=x(b-a)(b+a)$, which is impossible. Similarly we can show that $y\ne z$ and $x\ne z$.
Let $p$ be any prime divisor of $6m$. If $p\ge 7$ then it is easy to check that only one of the numbers $n$, $n+1$, $n+2$, and $3n+1$ is divisible by $p$. It follows that none of $x$, $y$, $z$, and $t$ is divisible by $p$, because otherwise this number would also be divisible by $p^2$, which is impossible. Similarly we can show that neither $x$ nor $y$ is divisible by $5$. So $z$ is divisible by $5$ iff $t$ is divisible by $5$. Thus we have $x,y\in\{1,2,3,6\}$, $z\in\{1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30\}$, and $t\in\{1,2,5,10\}$. Moreover, $t\equiv 1\pmod 3$, so  $t\in\{1,10\}$.
Exactly one of $x$, $y$, and $z$ is divisible by $3$. Moreover, if $x$ is divisible by $3$ then $n\equiv 0\pmod 3$, so $y=1$; if $y$ is divisible by $3$ then $n\equiv 2\pmod 3$, so $x=2$; and if $z$ is divisible by $3$ then $n\equiv 1\pmod 3$, so $x=1$ and $y=2$.
Finally, if $n$ is even then the numbers $y$ and $t$ are odd, and exactly one of the numbers $x$ and $z$ is even. If $n$ is odd then the numbers $x$ and $z$ are odd, and exactly one of the numbers $y$ and $t$ is even. Thus exactly one of $x$, $y$, $z$, and $t$ is even.
The number $z$ is odd, because otherwise $x$, $y$, and $t$ are distinct odd numbers from
$\{1,3\}$, which is impossible. Thus $z\in\{1,3,5,15\}$.
If $t=1$ then $z\in\{1,3\}$ and either $x$ is odd and $y$ is even or $x$ is even and $y$ is odd. The above arguments imply that in the former case $x=1$, $y=2$, and $z=3$ and in the latter case
$x=2$, $y=3$, and $z=1$.
In the former case $$5=3(n+2)-(3n+1)=9c^2-d^2=(3c+d)(3c-d),$$ so $c=1$, $d=2$ and $n=1$, which provides the first solution. In the latter case $$2=3(n+1)-(3n+1)=9b^2-d^2=(3b+d)(3b-d),$$ which is impossible.
So there remains the only (possibly) nonelementary case.
Namely, if $t=10$ then $\{x,y\}=\{1,3\}$ and so $x=3$, $y=1$, and $z=5$.
Moreover $3a^2=(b+1)(b-1)$.
Since $t=10$, $3n+1$ is even and so $n$ and $a$ are odd.
Therefore there exist natural numbers $e$ and $f$ such that either $b+1=e^2$ and $b-1=3f^2$ or
$b+1=3e^2$ and $b-1=f^2$. But the former case is impossible because then $3f^2+2=e^2$.
Thus we have to solve the following Diophantine system:
$$\begin{cases}
3e^2=f^2+2\\
5c^2=f^4+2f^2+2\\
3c^2=2d^2+1
\end{cases}$$
Then
$$\begin{align*}
c^2&=2(3c^2)-5c^2\\
&= 2(2d^2+1)-(f^4+2f^2+2)\\
&= 4d^2-f^4-2f^2\\
&= 4d^2-f^2(f^2+2)\\
&= 4d^2-3f^2e^2.
\end{align*}$$
Thus $(2d+c)(2d-c)=3(fe)^2$. Since $2d$ and $c$ are coprime, there exist natural numbers $g$ and $h$ such that either $2d+c=g^2$ and $2d-c=3h^2$, or $2d+c=3g^2$ and $2d-c=h^2$.
In the former case $4d=g^2+3h^2$, $2c=g^2-3h^2$, so
$$\begin{align*}
3((g^2-3h^2)/2)^2&=2((g^2+3h^2)/4)^2+1\\
6(g^2-3h^2)^2&=(g^2+3h^2)^2+8\\
6g^4-36g^2h^2+54h^4&=g^4+6g^2h^2+9h^4+8\\
5g^4-42g^2h^2+45h^4&=8.
\end{align*}$$
In the latter case $4d=3g^2+h^2$, $2c=3g^2-h^2$, so
$$\begin{align*}
3((3g^2-h^2)/2)^2&=2((3g^2+h^2)/4)^2+1\\
6(3g^2-h^2)^2&=(3g^2+h^2)^2+8\\
54g^4-36g^2h^2+6h^2&=9g^4+6g^2h^2+h^4+8\\
45g^4-42g^2h^2+5h^4&=8.\\
\end{align*}$$
So in both cases we have to solve the Diophantine equation $$45x^4-42x^2y^2+5y^4=8.$$
I failed to do this, so I asked a separate question on its solutions, and Sil showed
that its only natural solution is $(x,y)=(1,1)$.
Thus in the former case we have $2d+c=g^2=1$, which is impossible. In the latter case we have $2d+c=3g^2=3$ and $2d-c=h^2=1$, so $d=c=1$, and $n=3$, which provides the second solution.

Even if you didn't manage to completely solve this, this is a lot of progress, thank you!

@ElliottPrice With Sil's help I managed to complete the answer.
